# Lottie Animation width not setting in android matchparent

Tags: android, width, lottie

[image]

Hello, all I am using this Lottie animation  https://lottiefiles.com/117-progress-bar. when I say match parent this is what I see.  I need to increase the width. How can I achieve that?

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="progress_bar.json"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transmitting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
        android:text="Transmitting..."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the Lottie animations which are created, do not fill the complete Viewport. You have to manually give `layout_width` or `layout_height` in `dp`, or scale the drawable according to your need. You cannot change the dimensions in the .json file provided as all property values are relative to the original size.

You can try the below code to scale the `Drawable` inside the `LottieAnimationView`

```
LottieAnimationView animationView = findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
LottieDrawable drawable = new LottieDrawable();
LottieComposition.Factory.fromAssetFileName(this, "progress_bar.json",(composition -> 
{
    drawable.setComposition(composition);
    drawable.playAnimation();
    drawable.setScale(4);
    animationView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

}));
```

If you add the animation dynamically using above code, don't forget to remove `app:lottie_fileName` tag from your `LottieAnimationView`.

Comment: Where did you get `4` from when setting scale?

Comment: It's the amount of scale you want to set. You can adjust it whatever you want. Based on the image provided, I figured 4 would be the appropriate scale for given Lottie Animation.

Comment: So you're just basing the scale off of an estimate?

Comment: Yes, there isn't any other way to scale the drawable inside LottieAnimationView without creating a new one with newer property values. There are some animations which work without scaling, which are fit appropriately on canvas while creating the animation.

Comment: How can I know during runtime the size (width,height) of the Lottie animation? Is it static, never changing for all frames?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It's been a while since I last used Lottie. But there must definitely be a way to get it through the library. Least headache free way of dealing with it is making your designers create animations which fill the viewport as required instead of doing it manually through code.